# How to write query for joining two tables in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-3.5, django-orm

Here, what I want is to join two tables, increment **like value** in Post table, add another row in UserLikes tables with current User, PostId, `has_liked = True`. Also checking if the current user has already liked the current Post or not? Below is my code.

**models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=140)
    url = models.FileField("URL")
    likes = models.IntegerField("Likes", default=0)
    by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + str(self.by)

class UserLikes(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    has_liked = models.BooleanField("Liked", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post) + ' by ' + str(self.user)
```

**views.py**

```
def like(request, pk):
    if request.POST :
        post = get_object_or_404(Posts, pk=pk)
        print(request.user)
        obj = UserLikes.objects.filter(post_id__in=post.id, user=request.user)
        try:
            if obj.has_liked is not True:
                obj.post_id = post.id
                obj.user = request.user
                obj.has_liked = True
                obj.save()

            post.likes = str(int(post.likes) + 1)
            post.save()
        except AttributeError:
            return HttpResponse(post.likes)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(post.likes, {'like': 'disabled'})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/like/$', views.like, name='likes'),
```

So, what would be the query, in views.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `likes` field on your `Post` model is just duplicating data, instead just get the number of likes with a query, perhaps even make it a property of `Post` if you need to use it a lot

```
@property
def number_of_likes(self):
    return self.userlikes_set.count()
```

The rest then becomes trivial, just add a userlike for this instance.

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, but what I can not understand is how to limit each user to like it only once and store it in the `UserLikes` table. Also how to retrieve it, that is, what would be the query, when Index page is opened?

Comment: @CapJ if you only want one like per user, per post, just set `unique_together = ('post', 'user')` in the `UserLikes` model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Thank you @elkubo that did helped me.